# Enable Flash with Chromedriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, flash, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to enable Adobe Flash Player in chromedriver using python. I've gone through a number of attempts including:

```
prefs = {'plugins.plugins_enabled': 'Adobe Flash Player'}

prefs = {'plugins.plugins_list' : [{'enabled':True,'name':'Adobe Flash 
Player'}]}

prefs = {
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins': 1,
    'profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player': 1
}
```

along with a few other variations that I found from the top google results regarding this issue.

Comment: Isn't _Flash_ enabled by _default_ within _Chrome_

Comment: @DebanjanB From what I've seen, it is not enabled by default on Chromedriver. I've been able to accomplish what I'm trying to do once before on a bit of test code that I mistakenly trashed a while ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up solving this with the following code:

```
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-
     player": 1,
    "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "https://url.com"
}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the complete solution starting from import.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "ENTER THE URL HERE"
}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```